# How to calculate $\int_{\partial D(0;a)} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How to calculate $\displaystyle\int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)}$ when $|a|<r<|b|$?.

**My first idea:** I tried to separate by partial fractions, so for some $A,B$
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{Adz}{z-a} + \int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{Bdz}{z-b},
\end{equation}
and, by Cauchy integral formula, considering $f\equiv 1$ (is holomorphic)
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{Adz}{z-a} = A2\pi i,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{Bdz}{z-b} = B2\pi i.
\end{equation}
with which we get what we want. Is this procedure correct?

**My second idea:** Again reasoning by the Cauchy integral formula, considering $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-b}$ holomorphic on $D(0;r)$, then
\begin{equation}
    \int_{\partial D(0;r)} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)} = 2\pi i \frac{1}{a-b}.
\end{equation}
Is this procedure correct?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is correct and it leads to the right answer. The first method also works, if you use the fact that$$\frac1{(z-a)(z-b)}=\frac1{a-b}\left(\frac1{z-a}-\frac1{z-b}\right)$$together with the fact that$$\oint_{\partial D(0,r)}\frac1{z-a}\,\mathrm dz=1\quad\text{ and }\quad\oint_{\partial D(0,r)}\frac1{z-b}\,\mathrm dz=0.$$

Comment: O perfect! Thank you!